# How to use "routerLinkActive" with query params in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, parameters, routes, routerlinkactive

I have a problem in Angular: I have three links, one of them has query params (due to using a resolver). If I click the first and the third link, the `routerLinkActive` is set. If I click the second link `routerLinkActive` is set too. But if I change the query parameter inside the component `routerLinkActive` gets unset.

So, I need to ignore the query params. But how does it work? Can anyone help me?

Here is my simple code:

```
<div class="col-12">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a 
              class="nav-link" 
              routerLink="/einstellungen/allgemein"                             
              routerLinkActive="active">
              Allgemein
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a 
              class="nav-link" 
              [routerLink]="['/einstellungen/kalender']" 
              [queryParams]="{branch: myBranches[0].id}" 
              routerLinkActive="active"
              [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: false}">
              Kalender verwalten
           </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a 
              class="nav-link" 
              *ngIf="user.is_admin" 
              routerLink="/einstellungen/filialen" 
              routerLinkActive="active">
              Filialen verwalten
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

RouteLinkActive will work only with exact query params. You may try passing {exact: false} as routerLinkActiveOptions. If that doesn't work

You can call a function inside [class.active] attributes.

```
<a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/einstellungen/kalender']" [queryParams]="{branch: myBranches[0].id}" [class.active]="isLinkActive('/my-link')">Kalender verwalten</a>

isLinkActive(url): boolean {
   const queryParamsIndex = this.router.url.indexOf('?');
   const baseUrl = queryParamsIndex === -1 ? this.router.url : 
   this.router.url.slice(0, queryParamsIndex);
   return baseUrl === url;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Unfortunately it seems to be a bit cumbersome way. But it works!

Comment: Adding `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: false}"` worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: You can try to input an `IsActiveMatchOptions` object to the `RouterLinkActive` (https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive#properties) and adjust `queryParams: 'exact' | 'subset' | 'ignored'` - hope it helps someone

Answer (score 2):

In the **component.ts:**

```
withoutQueryParams$: Observable<boolean>;

ngOnInit() {
    this.withoutQueryParams$ = this.route.queryParams.pipe(
        map(params => Object.keys(params).length === 0)
    );
}
```

In the **template.html:**

```
[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: withoutQueryParams$ | async }"
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. All other answers replace```routerLinkActive``` with ```[class.active]```.

Answer (score 0):

Using a hidden anchor tag and an html template variable:

```
<a [routerLink]="/einstellungen/kalender" routerLinkActive="" #rla="routerLinkActive" hidden></a>
<a 
   class="nav-link" 
   [routerLink]="['/einstellungen/kalender']" 
   [queryParams]="{branch: myBranches[0].id}" 
   [class.active]="rla.isActive">
   Kalender verwalten
 </a>
```

Comment: This works, thank you. How to deal with more than a link? Have I to create an hidden `a` for every link and multiple `#rla` (#rla1, #rla2 and so on)?