# How can I set routerLinkActive for this paths?

Tags: angular, router

I have such navbar with such items : Users, Categories, Products, etc. Their routes are `Main/Users`, `Main/Categories`.
I have highlited items with `routerLinkActive`, but i also want to highlight Users, when route is

```
Main/User?UserId=4
```

How can i achieve this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use "routerLinkActive" with query params in Angular 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52037979/how-to-use-routerlinkactive-with-query-params-in-angular-6)

Comment: Will it work, because Main/Users and Main/User?UserId=4 are completly different routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`queryParams` is another input of `routerLink` where they can be passed like follows

```
<a [routerLink]="['Main/User']" [queryParams]="{UserId: 2}"></a>
```

Comment: Will it work, because Main/Users and Main/User?UserId=4 are completly different routes?